# how to compare dict data within existing excel file

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, xlrd

how could I compare the data that I got in dictionary format with the existing xlsx file.
Dictionary keys are same as the excel header. What is the easy way to compare? 
Here is the example:
Data in Dict:

```
{'Sheet1': [{'ID': 1.0, 'NAME': 'hostname1', 'IP_ADDRESS': '192.168.1.1', 'STATUS': 'completed'}, {'ID': 2.0, 'NAME': 'hostname2', 'IP_ADDRESS': '192.168.1.2', 'STATUS': 'completed'}, {'ID': 3.0, 'NAME': 'hostname3', 'IP_ADDRESS': '192.168.1.3', 'STATUS': 'in_progress'}, {'ID': 4.0, 'NAME': 'hostname4', 'IP_ADDRESS': '192.168.1.4', 'STATUS': 'completed'}]}
```

Excel file: 
  [image]

I would like to compare the dict value against the excel file (by the sheet), If the value is different in the Dict, update the excel file. If the entry doesn't exist in the excel simply add the new entry in the excel.

How should I start? compare and update and extend new entry in the excel file sheet. Thanks

##### Update

```
def writexlsx_multi_sheets(filename, data, sheet_name, **to_excel_kwargs):

from openpyxl import load_workbook

orginalDF = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
newDF = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
if 'engine' in to_excel_kwargs:
    to_excel_kwargs.pop('engine')

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = load_workbook(filename)
writer.sheets = {ws.title:ws for ws in writer.book.worksheets}
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

if not orginalDF.equals(newDF):
    result = orginalDF.combine_first(newDF)
    result.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
    writer.save()
else:
    return False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, convert your dictionary to a data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'ID': 1.0, 'NAME': 'hostname1', 'IP_ADDRESS': '192.168.1.1', 'STATUS': 'completed'}, {'ID': 2.0, 'NAME': 'hostname2', 'IP_ADDRESS': '192.168.1.2', 'STATUS': 'completed'}, {'ID': 3.0, 'NAME': 'hostname3', 'IP_ADDRESS': '192.168.1.3', 'STATUS': 'in_progress'}, {'ID': 4.0, 'NAME': 'hostname4', 'IP_ADDRESS': '192.168.1.4', 'STATUS': 'completed'}
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df1
# output

   ID       NAME   IP_ADDRESS       STATUS
0   1  hostname1  192.168.1.1    completed
1   2  hostname2  192.168.1.2    completed
2   3  hostname3  192.168.1.3  in_progress
3   4  hostname4  192.168.1.4    completed
```

Then read your xlsx file to another data frame. let's assume you have one fewer data in excel file

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('filename')
df2

# output
   ID       NAME   IP_ADDRESS       STATUS
0   1  hostname1  192.168.1.1    completed
1   2  hostname2  192.168.1.2    completed
2   3  hostname3  192.168.1.3    NaN
```

now use `combine_first()` function to check

```
df3 = df2.combine_first(df1)
df3

# output
  ID       NAME   IP_ADDRESS       STATUS
0  1  hostname1  192.168.1.1    completed
1  2  hostname2  192.168.1.2    completed
2  3  hostname3  192.168.1.3  in_progress
3  4  hostname4  192.168.1.4    completed
```

After comparing everything you can save it to the excel file

```
df3.to_csv('filename')
```

Comment: Thanks, looks simple, will `to_csv()` convert back to `.xlsx`? within the same sheet?

Comment: It create another sheet, is it possible to update data using existing sheet?

Comment: Is dict data is same as the excel sheet, I won't want to touch the excel sheet. How to check that? thanks

Comment: you can't compare excel file and dict data directly but after converting both of them into a data frame you can check for example in our case `df1.equals(df2)` it will yield `True` or `False`

Comment: Thanks, I have update the code. Do you see any issue with the code?